# How to determine if battery tabbing nickel strip is steel or pure nickel?

Tags: batteries, nickel

I'm not sure if this Stack Exchange section is the most appropriate for this question.  Please provide guidance if I need to move to a different section.

I am about to start building some Li-Ion battery packs that do not have solder tabs.  The standard method for doing this is to use a spot welder and nickel strip.

I ordered some strip that is described as "pure nickel".  However, it is not welding as I expect it to.  Cutting the strip with either side cutters or tin snips feels exactly like cutting steel.  I expected the nickel to be softer.

I am looking for a method or technique that I can use to determine if what I was shipped is in fact pure nickel or if it is nickel-plated steel.

Comment: What do you have in the way of equipment available? Do you have a bench power supply that can operate in current limited mode and one or two multi-meters? It may be feasible to directly measure the resistance of the whole long strip. Also, magnets stick much more strongly to steel than nickel. So I think you would be able to tell the difference that way, too.

Comment: @mkeith How weak are we talking about nickel? Weak enough that you would not use it for a fridge magnet?

Comment: I just remember sticking a magnet to a piece of nickel and thinking the attraction  was much weaker than steel. Not very quantitative. But yeah, it seemed too weak for refrigerator magnets to be reliable. I was using a strong magnet (from a BLDC motor).

Answer (score 2):

You could do a quick spark test, but I suggest sanding the surface layer and then immersing the strip in brine. If it is steel you’ll get a layer of rust in a matter of hours.

As a photograph this should be sufficient ‘proof’ to get a refund or replacement, if that is what you are going for.

Comment: Use clean sandpaper. Don't use a file. If you accidentally introduce iron or steel particles those may rust and confuse matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to immerse anyways to rust it then you might as well also do what archimedes did and measure the water displacement, weigh it, and calculate the density. Will probably need to toss in multiple tabs into a graduated cylinder to get the displacement to be measurable.

Or just get it wet and take a hair dryer to it.

Comment: If OP has calipers it may be easier to calculate the volume based on dimensions.

Comment: @mkeith Maybe. I guess it depends  on the specific shape of the tabs. The difference in density between iron and nickel is only 12%

Comment: Very true. I was assuming it was one long ribbon of nickel (allegedly). But that might not be the case.